# Quais os passos para criar uma imagem de Docker para Ubuntu 16:04, php 5.6 e apache (com Composer, xdebug, phpunit, npm e REDIS)?

Tags: php, imagem, ubuntu, docker

Sou iniciante em Docker e estou tentando criar uma imagem com as seguintes especificações:

1. O OS fonte tem que ser o Ubuntu 16.04 original. Não posso usar imagens já disponíveis no docker hub;
2. Tem que ter instalado apache - última versão;
3. Tem que ter instalado php e algumas bibliotecas. Tem que ser php 5.5.38 (ideal) ou 5.X último update ou em último caso 5.6.X último update.
4. Tem que ter instalado o REDIS.
5. O REDIS, APACHE e php devem estar disponíveis assim que o container for criado, ou seja, inicializados automaticamente.
6. A raíz do sistema (/var/www/html) deve apontar para um volume /home/username/vhosts/mySite. O host é um MAC OS.
7. O sistema tem que ser acessado do browser do host através de mysite-dev1 ou mysite-dev2 ou mysite-devN ...

O objetivo final é criar uma imagem que vai ser compartilhada entre todos os desenvolvedores da empresa.

Este é o **Dockerfile** que estou usando:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#1
RUN apt-get update
#2
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
#3
RUN apt-get install -y php5
#4
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
#5
RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis

COPY /home/username/vhosts/mySite /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Em seguida estou encontrando alguns errors:

Operação #3,
php5 não faz parte do package list do ubuntu 16.04. Deste [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported) verifica-se que ele precisa ser atualizado da seguinte maneira:

```
#6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Operação #6,
Recebo um erro dizendo que o `sudo` não é reconhecido como comando (mesmo se tento rodar em modo iterativo no terminal -ti). [Fazendo uma pesquisa](https://github.com/threatstream/mhn/issues/284) verifico que o `sudo` não está habilitado na imagem do Ubuntu16.04.

Se eu tento rodar sem o sudo via terminal (`docker run -ti ...`), recebo uma mensagem dizendo que `add-apt-repository` não encontrado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Fazendo uma [outra pesquisa](https://github.com/threatstream/mhn/issues/284) sobre esse erro descubro que `add-apt-repository` também não está disponível para imagens de Ubuntu 14.04 em docker. E pelo visto tbm não está disponível para 16.04. A solução proposta é rodar:

```
#7
apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Rodando essa operação #7 recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fazendo uma outra pesquisa, acho esse [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786334/proxy-problems-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-apt-1-2) que sugere a modificação do `apt.conf` localizado em `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. 
E esse é o conteúdo do diretório apt de dentro da imagem do ubuntu 16.04
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Ou seja, não possui `apt.conf`. Fazendo uma pesquisa em alguns [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/472605/how-to-set-proxy-configuration) encontro que **apt.conf** precisa ser criado.

A minha conclusão é que eu devo estar fazendo algo muito errado pois o objetivo é somente instalar **php5.6** em Ubuntu16.04.

Concluindo, alguém saberia dizer alguma maneira já testada de se criar uma imagem com as características listadas anteriormente sem passar pelas etapas anteriores?

UPDATE:
Parece que outras [imagens](https://hub.docker.com/r/yarsoniy/php5.6/~/dockerfile/) estão com o mesmo problema quando tentam instalar a versão 5.6 do php.

Comment: Um container não deve ter todos esses elementos. REDIS, PHP, APACHE são 3 containers. Diferente de uma VM, com docker estamos falando de virtualização de PROCESSO, não de máquinas virtuais, portanto o que você está querendo, não deveria ser feito dessa forma. Preparei uma wiki com essa dúvida, ela é muito recorrente | https://github.com/luizcarlosfaria/kb/wiki/FAQ-Docker-LAMP

Comment: Luiz, concordo 100% com vc. Como eu disse, ainda sou iniciante em Docker, mas não em arquitetura de sistemas. Acho que o Docker segue a idéia de microsserviços indo mais ao extremo. Como vc disse, até mandando para um container o servidor e para o outro o php. O problema é que as vezes numa empresa  a decisão não é tomada por uma pessoa só e até que todos consigam entender os benefícios de containers com funções únicas leva um tempo. Eu gostei da sua publicação. Já copiei o link para o meu grupo de FullStack Update.

Comment: Para a minha questão, acabei usando uma imagem Php oficial do Docker Hub, já pronta que já possui php e apache em Linux, embora não seja ubuntu. https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: a questão de ter vários processos distintos como redis e php no mesmo container, não há uma questão como "depende" ou "dependendo do cenário", está categoricamente errado. Esse tipo de abordagem é abominada por motivos simples da arquitetura do docker. Docker usa features do kernel para abstrair o isolamento de PROCESSOS, somente. Não estamos falando de um environment virtual, estamos falando de um processo virtual. E isso muda completamente o viés da coisa. Em um SO qualquer você teria uma instalação do Redis, outra instalação do PHP (mesmo que na mesma máquina)

Comment: ... cada elemento é independente, mesmo que na mesma máquina. A questão é que Docker trabalha assim também. O fato é que se você criar uma imagem  com 2 coisas, como por exemplo PHP e NGINX que ao primeiro olhar pode até ser algo afim: está errado. PHP é php, nginx é nginx. Fazendo qualquer coisa diferente, você vai ter problemas com containers morrendo sem motivo, baixo reaproveitamento de imagens e layers, sobreposição de responsabilidade. Enfim, vai ter diversos problemas.

Comment: Entendido e concordo com vc Luiz.  À medida que trabalho mais com o Docker vou entendendo a sua ideologia. A minha próxima versão não terá mais REDIS acoplado no container.

Answer (score 0):

Embora a ideologia do Docker seja de individualizar ao máximo os processos executando cada um deles em containers diferentes, eu vou postar aqui a minha solução com o REDIS dentro de um só container.

Vale notar as observações do @Luiz Carlos. Usar REDIS dentro de um mesmo container rodando php, apache, etc, não é uma boa prática.

O **Dockerfile**:
Preparado com php 5.6, Apache, PHPUnit, xdebug, REDIS, Composer, NPM.

```
FROM php:5-apache

## Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y figlet

RUN figlet Docker_Build

## UTILITIES
RUN figlet vim
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN figlet wget
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN figlet CURL
RUN apt-get install -y curl

##===================================================== > ffmpeg stufs

## NOTE: Debian Jessie and later no longer include the ffmpeg, however you have 3 options for installing ffmpeg // https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian

## list of installed library packages only =>  https://askubuntu.com/questions/434154/how-to-get-the-list-of-installed-library-packages-only
#ldconfig -v                # -v it will show the libraries versions
#ldconfig -v | grep libname # Use grep to find a specific library by name.
#RUN /sbin/ldconfig -p

## Installed 
#RUN figlet
#RUN apt-get install -y libav-tools

## https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian
#root@b6a73f142787:/var/www/html# apt-cache search ffmpeg => List all plugins associated with ffmpeg

#cmus-plugin-ffmpeg - lightweight ncurses audio player (FFmpeg plugin)
RUN figlet cmus
RUN apt-get install -y cmus

#ffmpeg2theora - Theora video encoder using ffmpeg
RUN figlet ffmpeg2theora
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg2theora

#ffmpegthumbnailer - fast and lightweight video thumbnailer
RUN figlet ffmpegthumbnailer
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpegthumbnailer

#ffmpegthumbnailer-dbg - debugging informations for ffmpegthumbnailer
RUN figlet ffmpegthumbnailer
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpegthumbnailer-dbg

#libffmpegthumbnailer-dev - development files for ffmpegthumbnailer
RUN figlet libffmpegthumbnailer
RUN apt-get install -y libffmpegthumbnailer-dev

#libffmpegthumbnailer4 - shared library for ffmpegthumbnailer
RUN figlet libffmpegthumbnailer4
RUN apt-get install -y libffmpegthumbnailer4

#ffmpegthumbs - video thumbnail generator using ffmpeg
RUN figlet ffmpegthumbs
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpegthumbs

#libffms2-3 - Cross platform ffmpeg wrapper library
RUN figlet libffms2
RUN apt-get install -y libffms2-3

#gmerlin-encoders-ffmpeg - ffmpeg encoders for Gmerlin
RUN figlet
RUN apt-get install -y gmerlin-encoders-ffmpeg

#libpostproc-dev - FFmpeg derived postprocessing library - development headers
RUN figlet libpostproc
RUN apt-get install -y libpostproc-dev

#libpostproc52 - FFmpeg derived postprocessing library
RUN figlet libpostproc52
RUN apt-get install -y libpostproc52

#moc-ffmpeg-plugin - ncurses based console audio player - ffmpeg plugin
RUN figlet moc-ffmpeg-plugin
RUN apt-get install -y moc-ffmpeg-plugin

#libtaoframework-ffmpeg-cil-dev - Tao CLI binding for FFmpeg - development files
RUN figlet libtaoframework
RUN apt-get install -y libtaoframework-ffmpeg-cil-dev

#libtaoframework-ffmpeg0.4-cil - Tao CLI binding for FFmpeg
RUN figlet libtaoframework
RUN apt-get install -y libtaoframework-ffmpeg0.4-cil

#winff - graphical video and audio batch converter using ffmpeg or avconv
RUN figlet winff
RUN apt-get install -y winff

#libxine2-ffmpeg - MPEG-related plugins for libxine2
RUN figlet libxine2
RUN apt-get install -y libxine2-ffmpeg

## ListInstalledPackages => https://wiki.debian.org/ListInstalledPackages
#RUN dpkg-query -l

## NOTE:
##need setup php variables date and maxupload file and others variables. ==> https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/servers/php/manage-php-ini-options-from-command-line-on-debian

##Install FFmpeg on Debian  => https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian
#https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
## System modules

#RUN apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
#RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

## ====================================================================== > End of ffmpeg stufs



## APACHE2  basic installation
RUN figlet APACHE2
RUN apachectl -M
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apachectl -M


## ====================================================================== > PHP modules

## Note: when installing from php5 for some modules we need to copy from php5/mods-available to local/etc/php/conf.d and create a simbolic link
RUN figlet PHP_MODULES
RUN php -m

RUN apt-get install -y php5-common

RUN apt-get install -y php-calendar
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/calendar.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/calendar.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/calendar.so

#RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar 

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mhash
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mhash.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mhash.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mhash.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-intl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mysql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysql.so

RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gd
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gd.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-vtkgdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/vtkgdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/vtkgdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/vtkgdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-ldap
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ldap.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xsl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xsl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-tidy
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/tidy.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/tidy.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/tidy.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xmlrpc
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xmlrpc.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xmlrpc.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-pgsql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pgsql.so


RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/readline.so

#RUN apt-get install -y php5-snmp
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/snmp.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/snmp.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/snmp.so

RUN figlet PHP_MODULES
RUN php -m

## PHP extra modules
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-date-parser  ##The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y php-horde-date-parser' returned a non-zero code: 100
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-date
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-timezone
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-timeobjects
#RUN apt-get install -y php-timer



#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-icalendar
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-kronolith
#RUN apt-get install -y php-doctrine-dbal
#RUN apt-get install -y phpldapadmin
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-ldap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-net-ldap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-net-ldap2
#RUN apt-get install -y php-mdb2-driver-pgsql
#RUN apt-get install -y libnusoap-php
#RUN apt-get install -y php-soap
#RUN apt-get install -y php-fxsl
#RUN apt-get install -y php-horde-text-filter-csstidy
#RUN apt-get install -y php-pclzip
#RUN apt-get install -y libphp-pclzip

#RUN apt-get update

#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/json.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/json.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/json.so


#Manage PHP ini options from command line on Debian => https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/servers/php/manage-php-ini-options-from-command-line-on-debian
#RUN apt-get install -y php5-cli


### Note: Compare content

#PHP5
#cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
#cd /etc/php5/mods-available/


#PHP 
#cd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
#cd /usr/lib/php5/20131226/



## Note: when module is php5 need to make it available inside php/extensions (create a simbolic link)
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/MODULE.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/MODULE.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/MODULE.so


## ====================================================================== > End of PHP modules




## ====================================================================== > REDIS
RUN figlet REDIS
RUN apt-get install -y telnet redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server

## ====================================================================== > NPM
RUN figlet NPM
RUN apt-get install -y npm

## ====================================================================== > COPYING php.ini
RUN figlet COPYING__php.ini
RUN cp /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN ls -l /usr/local/etc/

## ====================================================================== > XDEBUG
# XDEBUG EXTENSION FOR PHP | DOCUMENTATION => https://xdebug.org/docs/remote 
#
# install xdebug and enable it. This block of code goes through the installion from source and compiling steps found
# on the xdebug website
# https://xdebug.org/docs/install
RUN figlet INSTALLING__XDEBUG
RUN cd /tmp \
    && wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.5.4.tgz \
    && tar -xvzf xdebug-2.5.4.tgz \
    && cd xdebug-2.5.4 \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure  \
    && make \
    && cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

RUN figlet INSIDE_no-debug-non-zts-20131226/         
RUN ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/



#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596381/how-to-setup-an-variable-env-inside-dockerfile-to-be-overriden-in-a-docker-conta?noredirect=1#comment82150863_47596381
# ADD xdebug configurations
RUN figlet SETTING__XDEBUG__php.ini
RUN { \
        echo '[xdebug]'; \
        echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000'; \  
        echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'; \
        echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug'; \
        echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_host=$REMOTE_HOST'; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini



RUN figlet XDEGUB__IN__php.ini
RUN cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


#With an unknown IP/multiple developers
#xdebug.remote_host
#Type: string, Default value: localhost
#Selects the host where the debug client is running, you can either use a host name, IP address, 
#or 'unix:///path/to/sock' for a Unix domain socket. 
#This setting is ignored if xdebug.remote_connect_back is enabled.

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x
#lsof -i :9001
#netstat -anv | grep 9001


#https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac
#ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1
#   inet 10.20.1.210 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 10.20.1.255

#https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line
#ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'

#https://serversforhackers.com/c/getting-xdebug-working

#Debug your PHP in Docker with Intellij/PHPStorm and Xdebug
#https://gist.github.com/chadrien/c90927ec2d160ffea9c4



#https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/102
#Pointing 9000 to php-fpm with xdebug enabled
#https://forums.docker.com/t/ip-address-for-xdebug/10460/22







## ====================================================================== > COMPOSER

RUN figlet Escape_SUDO
RUN exit

RUN figlet Install__COMPOSER
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

RUN composer


## ====================================================================== > PhpUnit

RUN figlet PhpUnit
RUN curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.6.0.phar -L -o phpunit.phar
RUN chmod +x phpunit.phar
RUN mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit



RUN figlet COPYING_entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN figlet Permission_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]

# EXPOSE - PORTS
RUN figlet EXPOSE_PORTS
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]



## ====================================================================== > Extra notes

## Clean up Docker
#docker rm $(docker ps -a)
#docker rmi $(docker images)
#docker build -t my_img . 

## RUN REDIS 
#Open up another terminal
#docker  exec -it  xxxxxCOntainerId bash 
#root@bxxxxxCOntainerId:/var/www/html# redis-server

#If another terminal is needed to get acces to the container:
#Open up another terminal
#docker  exec -it  xxxxxCOntainerId bash 

## ============================         Export the desired image    
## Exit the container and commit in order to save the last state
#docker commit e4a01807684f my_new_name_img

## Check the created image my_new_name_img is there
#docker images
#REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
#my_new_name_img           latest              cc49bbaafd2d        15 seconds ago      771MB

## Tag the image // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svs-_9SAYz0
#docker tag my_new_name_img  my_account_docker_hub/my_new_name_img:v001   


## Login.
#docker login
#myusername
#mypassword

## Publish the image
#docker push my_account_docker_hub/my_new_name_img:v001

#Remove all images and all containers 
#docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
#docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) 

#Using the image just created and stored in the cloud
##docker run -p 80:80  -v path_to_your_project_folder:/var/www/html -e REMOTE_HOST=192.67.10.0 my_account_docker_hub/my_new_name_img:v001 apache2-foreground
## ou
##docker run -p 80:80  -v path_to_your_project_folder:/var/www/html -e REMOTE_HOST=$REMOTE_HOST my_account_docker_hub/my_new_name_img:v001 apache2-foreground

#Note: REMOTE_HOST is your local IP. That value will be used inside xdebug.remote_host. 
#Esse valor é importante para permitir uma conexão entre o xdebug e o IDE, principalmente o Intellij ou o PHPstrom. 
#No primeiro exemplo a variável $REMOTE_HOST pode ser usada em um script BASH  
#REMOTE_HOST=`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'` 
#para carregar o container automaticamente sem necessidade de passar o IP

# Documentation
#    https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#proxy-configuration
#    https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/orgs/
#    https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/
#    https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app
#    http://jasani.org/2014/11/19/docker-now-supports-adding-host-mappings/
#    https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#parent-command
#    https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/orgs/#convert-a-user-to-an-organization
#    http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#chap_07
#    https://medium.com/ihme-tech/using-xdebug-with-intellij-inside-a-docker-container-dc8cbd844dc5
#    https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-commander
#    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQ3H_jhyW2w
#    https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/redis/
#    https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings
#    https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
#    http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html
#    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-text-file-in-shell-script-bash
#    http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.1/chapter07/hosts.html
#    http://www.linfo.org/cat.html
#    https://redislabs.com/blog/so-youre-looking-for-the-redis-gui/

#http://tarunlalwani.com/post/debugging-php-xdebug-docker/
#https://medium.com/ihme-tech/using-xdebug-with-intellij-inside-a-docker-container-dc8cbd844dc5
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357783/xdebug-with-intellij-and-docker-is-not-working-how-to-solve-it?noredirect=1#comment81686964_47357783
#https://xdebug.org/docs/remote
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263043/how-to-setup-docker-phpstorm-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04/46265103#46265103
#http://www.mysolutions.it/phpstorm-server-xdebug-configuration/    

# How could I ping my docker container from my host // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216830/how-could-i-ping-my-docker-container-from-my-host
# docker inspect 64ad351e115f give me "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
# How to get a Docker container's IP address from the host? docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 64ad351e115f 172.17.0.2
```

Esse é o **entrypoint.sh** que vai injetar o Ip dinamicamente no php.ini passando para o xdebug.remote_host :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Check if our environment variable has been passed.
if [ -z "${REMOTE_HOST}" ]
then
  echo "REMOTE_HOST has not been set."
  exit 1
else
  sed -i.bak "s/\$REMOTE_HOST/${REMOTE_HOST}/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
fi

exec "$@"
```